# db4o - ignore specific class property

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-3.5, db4o

Is there a way (meta property maybe) to tell db4o to simply ignore a specific property of a class?

I can't see anywhere to do that..

For my purpose I have a bunch of data entity that i need to persist now and then. I also sometimes need to hold a ref to a UI element associated with it, but I don't want db4o to persist that element when I update the object.

I can go around it by backing up, nulling the ref, saving, and finally restoring the reference but it seems really bad.

Anyway I can tell db4o to ignore it altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the [Transient](http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-7.4/net35/reference/) attribute to the specific field (db4o knowns nothing about properties)

```
public class Test
{
    [Transient] private string name;
    // ...
}
```

Best

Comment: ah yes, couldn't see while skimming through the doc.. odd name I guess

Comment: You can also use the NonSerialized attribute if you don't like the transient one. Anyway, for me the name "transient" makes sense.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Its actually right there in the doco, you just need the right search term :-)

Look in the docs for Transient Fields / Classes.